# USB Error when install Ubuntu on my PC

Tags: system-installation, 16.10

I'm trying to Dual Boot Ubuntu 16.10 on Windows 10 PC but when I try to Boot to the installer it says this:

```
hid-gereric 0003:2833:0031.0004: usb_submit_urb(ctrl) failed: -1
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

When you boot your LiveCD, press "e" to access the grub boot parameters.

Find this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=
```

And add the following: `"usbhid.quirks=<keyboard quirk>"`, in quotes, after `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=`.

You will need to research the line for your keyboard. For example, if you have a Corsair Keyboard, you need to change the `<keyboard quirk>` section of the command.

```
K65 RGB: usbhid.quirks=0x1B1C:0x1B17:0x20000408
K70: usbhid.quirks=0x1B1C:0x1B09:0x0x20000408
K70 RGB: usbhid.quirks=0x1B1C:0x1B13:0x20000408
K95: usbhid.quirks=0x1B1C:0x1B08:0x20000408
K95 RGB: usbhid.quirks=0x1B1C:0x1B11:0x20000408
Strafe: usbhid.quirks=0x1B1C:0x1B15:0x20000408
Strafe RGB: usbhid.quirks=0x1B1C:0x1B20:0x20000408
M65 RGB: usbhid.quirks=0x1B1C:0x1B12:0x20000408
Sabre RGB Optical: usbhid.quirks=0x1B1C:0x1B14:0x20000408
Sabre RGB Laser: usbhid.quirks=0x1B1C:0x1B19:0x20000408
Scimitar RGB: usbhid.quirks=0x1B1C:0x1B1E:0x20000408
```

Example:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="resume=UUID=376b974a-9cc7-4a48-9e6a-de19471107f2 usbhid.quirks=0x1B1C:0x1B12:0x20000000 quiet splash"
```

Hopefully this should work. However, after the installation, **you need to add these commands to /etc/default/grub**. Changes to the kernel parameters at boot are not persistent.

Use:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Insert the line after `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=`, exit, and run the command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: I do not see that lone on the editor

Comment: You do not see "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="?

Comment: No i did not see it

Comment: What keyboard do you have?

Comment: Roccat ryos Mk pro

Comment: Use a different keyboard in your install. I don't know of any usb-hid quirk codes for your keyboard.

Comment: OK I will try it when I get home